# Iterating 20k files from a Linux directory is slow on Python

Tags: python

I've 20 thousand rpm's in a directory and wanted to list all latest version rpm's from directory. Tried all possibility's nothing seems to be favoring. Any recommendations/ suggestions here ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It will guide us in helping you find a solution  you have not already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the repl buddy. I've used these methods
1. glob.glob(rpm_dir_path) and iterate loop split() filename for package name and version and find the latest. 
2. The other method is os.listdir() and iterate loop split() package name and versions, find the latest.

Comment: That's not an issue with Python. Most filesystems are not tuned to have such a large directory entry. Maybe you should split the repository into subdirectories first, like 1000 packages per subdirectory or one subdir per each letter. For instance, this is how [Debian main package repository](ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/) is organized.

Comment: @merlin2011 Didn't you read? He's tried *"all possibility's [sic]"* ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.listdir()` to get the content of the directory.

Iterate through the results.

Split the filename string to package name part and version part using `split()`.

Maintain the list of packages versions in a dictionary.

If the currently iterated version of package is newer than one stored in the dictionary update it.

At the end of the iteration print out the contents of the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude. I'm currently doing the same but the problem is in performance. It is slow if we follow the above method, any other recommendations that you can suggest me?

Comment: Without seeing any timing statistics, the performance limitation is not Python, but Linux file system. I suggest you use some sort of database to index your RPM files instead of just dumping them to a single directory - thus your question should be "how to maintain updated list of 20k files"

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called scandir that might help. It is an os.walk replacement.

Compare against `time ls > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you call "slow", doesn't it?

The code below takes

```
time python ./testling.py >/dev/null

0.0954809188843 s

real    0m0.776s
user    0m0.228s
sys     0m0.348s
```

on a 4 yrs old Quad core.

And pls attend - the significant profiling figure is the first line, the one < 0.1 s; real, user etc are **including** starting the interpreter, the generation of the test data and output to /dev/null.

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import uuid
import re
from random import seed, sample, randint
import itertools
import time

MIN_NUM_FILES=20000
ROOT="/tmp/foo/" + str(uuid.uuid4())
SUFFIX='.tmp'

PAT = re.compile(r"([0-9a-zA-F-]*)_([0-9]*)")
seed()

def prepare(): 
    current_count = 0
    while current_count  < MIN_NUM_FILES:
        stem = str(uuid.uuid4())
        lot_size = randint(10,100)
        versions = sample(xrange(1, 1000000), lot_size)
        for version in versions:
            open(stem + '_' + str(version) + SUFFIX, 'w').write('')
            current_count += 1


def find_newest():
    start = time.time()
    fns = glob.glob('*' + SUFFIX)
    fns.sort()
    d = {k:list(fn) 
            for k, fn  in itertools.groupby(
                fns, lambda x : str(PAT.match(x).group(1))
            )
    }    
    r = [key + "_" + str(max([int(PAT.match(s).group(2)) 
                                 for s in d[key]])) +  SUFFIX  for key in d]

    sys.stderr.write((str(time.time()  - start) + " s\n" ))    
    #for key in d:
    #    print(key, len(d[key]))
    return r



if __name__ == '__main__':
    cwd = os.curdir
    try:
        os.mkdir(ROOT) 
        os.chdir(ROOT)
        prepare()

        for fn in find_newest():
            print(fn)

        #file_names = glob.glob('*')
        #for fn in file_names:
            #os.remove(fn) 
    except:
        pass

    os.chdir(cwd)
#    os.rmdir(ROOT)
```

**No warranty, neither implied nor expressed.**

*Better **don't** play with rmdir, remove et al!*